# Lookaround with optional characters

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, stringr, lookbehind

I am trying to extract domains from a dataframe of urls, essentially removing the scheme (i.e., http, https, www) and top-level domain (i.e., com, org, gov). I currently to this in a step-wise manner (see `v1-3`) and believe I should be able to do this in a single step using lookarounds with optional characters, but my best attempt after testing things out, `v4`, is still not matching `v3`.

In pseudocode, I would like to: extract the part of the string preceded by http/s and/or www, and followed by com/org/io/gov.

Thank you for your help!

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

tibble::tribble(
  ~url,
  "http://example.org",
  "https://www.words.com/",
  "http://www.potato.io/some/more/text",
  "www.apple.sauce.gov/"
) |>
  mutate(
    v1 = str_remove(url, "^https?://"),
    v2 = str_remove(v1, "^www."),
    v3 = str_remove(v2, "\\.(com|org|io|gov).*")
  ) |>
  mutate(
    v4 = str_extract(url, "(?<=https?://(www\\.)?).*(?=\\.(com|org|io|gov))")
  ) |> 
  knitr::kable()
```

| url | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| http://example.org | example.org | example.org | example | example |
| https://www.words.com/ | [www.words.com/](http://www.words.com/) | words.com/ | words | www.words |
| http://www.potato.io/some/more/text | [www.potato.io/some/more/text](http://www.potato.io/some/more/text) | potato.io/some/more/text | potato | www.potato |
| [www.apple.sauce.gov/](http://www.apple.sauce.gov/) | [www.apple.sauce.gov/](http://www.apple.sauce.gov/) | apple.sauce.gov/ | apple.sauce | NA |

<sup>Created on 2022-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Instead of `[com|org|io|gov]`, you need `(com|org|io|gov)` if you mean to alternate char sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done without lookarounds.  From the start match the prefix string and then everything up to the last dot and then the rest.  Capture the part to the last dot and return it.

```
sub("^(https?://)?(www\\.)?(.*)\\..*$", "\\3", x)    
## [1] "example"     "words"       "potato"      "apple.sauce"
```

**2)** The urltools package can split the character strings giving a data frame with `subdomain`, `domain` and other columns.  Use `coalesce` to replace NA's in `subdomain` with an empty string, paste together the processed `subdomain` and `domain` and finally remove any `www.` or `.` prefix.

```
library(dplyr)
library(urltools)

x %>%
  domain %>%
  suffix_extract %>%
  with(paste0(coalesce(subdomain, ""), ".", domain)) %>%
  sub("^(www)?\\.?", "", .)
## [1] "example"     "words"       "potato"      "apple.sauce"
```

**3)** We can simplify (1) by making use of url_parse in the utils package and file_path_sans_ext in the tools package.  These come with R so they don't have to be installed.

```
library(tools)
library(utils)

sub("^(www)?\\.", "", file_path_sans_ext(url_parse(x)$domain))
## [1] "example"     "words"       "potato"      "apple.sauce"
```

This could also be written as a pipeline:

```
x |>
  url_parse() |>
  with(domain) |>
  file_path_sans_ext() |>
  sub("^(www)?\\.", "", x = _)
## [1] "example"     "words"       "potato"      "apple.sauce"
```

### Note

```
x <- c("http://example.org", "https://www.words.com/",
  "http://www.potato.io/some/more/text", "www.apple.sauce.gov/")
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps! However, I would like to capture "apple.sauce" rather than just "sauce". I'll check out url tools and see if I find a solution there.

Comment: Have fixed (1) and (2) and added (3).